# Apache Mod_Rewrite Question Mark

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect an incoming request with the following URL:

http://mywebsite.com/abc/mapserv.exe?map=123

to

[http://mywebsite.com/abc/mapserv.exe?map=C:\Mapserver\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\Mapfiles\123.map](http://mywebsite.com/abc/mapserv.exe?map=C:%5CMapserver%5Cms4w%5CApache%5Chtdocs%5CMapfiles%5C123.map)

I already managed to do simple mod_rewrites but the question mark is killing this one all the time. I am not able to adapt common Query String examples to my case so I need help with this exact case.

Comment: Please show us what you tried then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was still having trouble with the .exe url since it is not accessible if you dont deliver the parameters right when you send the request. And then the redirect wont fire. So I made a dummy mapserver.php file which allows setting a parameter like so:

http://mywebsite.com/abc/mapserver.php?map=123

After hours of trying I ended up with the following RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^map=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^mapserver.php?$ /cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C://Mapserver//ms4w//Apache//htdocs//Mapfiles//%1.map
```

Answer (score 2):

As though you did not show your try, you could test this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} map=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?map=C:\\Mapserver\\ms4w\\Apache\\htdocs\\Mapfiles\\%1.map [NE,L]
```

Rewrite flags used:
NE: Not Escape,
L: Last instruction to run.

Comment: Hello jacouh, thanks for your help even though I didnt even know how to start properly. Your code snippet helped me out, I change a few things and now it works. I posted my solution as an answer.